# Voting on locked questions causes score to become 0

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-count, locked, locked-questions

I discovered a minor bug. When you try to vote on a locked question you get an "error", which is fine, but then the displayed score turns to 0 from whatever it was originally. For example, on [How to send 100.000 emails weekly??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly):

[image: screenshot of post score 0]

Thanks in advance. Just in case, I'm using Chrome (latest version) on my Mac

Comment: @waiwai933 damn that was some sloppy writing!! for the love of christ "up-botes" (maybe has something to do with boat programming) hehe thanks for the edit! Sorry about that!

Comment: That *is* weird (and a little bit scary).  But the vote tally *does* come back if you refresh the page. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, found and fixed - this will be deployed shortly.

Comment: Thanks for that! As always, good job!!